# Access current user associated info in rendered template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I struggle with that problem for a few days, and now I decided to reach your help. I'm trying to display user points in rendered view. I have a template: `points/show_user_points.html` in which there are 2 lines:

```
<%= IO.inspect(@conn) %> 
You have used <%= @user.pool.used_points %>
```

In the terminal, I see that the `current_user: nil`.

This template is rendered in `page/index.html.eex`

```
<%= render EmployeeRewardAppWeb.PointsView, "show_user_points.html", conn: @conn, user: @current_user %>
```

where I also render another view

```
<%= render EmployeeRewardAppWeb.PointsView, "points_user_card.html", conn: @conn, user: user %>
```

In `page_controller` I render these views in such way:

```
      use EmployeeRewardAppWeb.Helpers.CurrentUser
def index(conn, _params, current_user) do
        users = Accounts.list_users
        |> Repo.preload(:pool)
        new_conn = assign(conn, :users, users)
         render(conn, "index.html", users: users, current_user: current_user)
  end

      
def show_single_user_points(conn, _params, current_user) do
        user = current_user
        id = user.id
        single_user = Accounts.get_user!(id)
        |> Repo.preload([:pool])
        render(conn, "show_user_points.html", single_user: current_user)
      end
```

CurrentUser Helper

```
defmodule EmployeeRewardAppWeb.Helpers.CurrentUser do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def action(%Plug.Conn{assigns: %{current_user: current_user}} = conn, _opts) do
        apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), [conn, conn.params, current_user])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My question is: How do I get access and display the `<%= @user.pool.used_points %>` in `points/show_user_points.html`? I was trying to place `show_single_user_points` in PointsController but it didn't change anything. I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is here:

```
use EmployeeRewardAppWeb.Helpers.CurrentUser

def index(conn, _params, current_user) do
  users = Accounts.list_users
         |> Repo.preload(:pool)

  new_conn = assign(conn, :users, users) # <-- you aren't using new_conn!!

  render(conn, "index.html", users: users, current_user: current_user)
end
```

When you modify the `conn` variable and bind it to the `new_conn` variable, *you aren't doing anything with it*.

Instead, you must pass the new updated version of the variable to your template:

```
  new_conn = assign(conn, :users, users)

  render(new_conn, "index.html", users: users, current_user: current_user)
```

Or, more idiomatically, continue the pipe:

```
def index(conn, _params, current_user) do
  users = Accounts.list_users
         |> Repo.preload(:pool)

  conn
  |> assign(:users, users)
  |> render("index.html", users: users, current_user: current_user)
end
```

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply! I changed the index function to what you showed here. I still have `<%= @current_user.pool.used_points %>` in the `show_user_points.html` and i see error `assign @current_user not available in eex template. Available assigns: [:conn, :user, :view_module, :view_template]`

Comment: I changed: `<%= render EmployeeRewardAppWeb.PointsView, "show_user_points.html", conn: @conn, user: @current_user %>` to `<%= render EmployeeRewardAppWeb.PointsView, "show_user_points.html", conn: @conn, current_user: @current_user %>` (kept your index function) and now I see such error: 
`function nil.pool/0 is undefined`

Comment: It looks like the current_user is still nil.